# particular topology on topological groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, topological-groups

Take $G$ an abelian additive group. I was looking about the following problem. If $G$ is topological we know (because of the translations are homeomorphisms) that the topology is uniquely determined by the neighborhoods of the $0.$ My question is the following

If I take a countable collection of subset of $G$, $\{G_n\}$, can I define a topology such that this is a fundamental system of neighoborhood and $G$ with this topology is a topological group?

I'm interested in the case where $G=G_0\supset G_1 \ ...$ are subgroups (for example the $I$-adic topology over a ring).

Comment: See the Birkhoff theorem that formulates the necessary and sufficient conditions. (Sometimes Kakutani-Birkhoff)

Comment: I find only version for Hausdorff topological groups and about metrizable groups. So I think that this is true. anyway I thought about a stright proof of the type: if I want that it is a topological group I define a local basis of neighborhoods of a point x as $x+G_{n}$ and then a proof that they "generate" a fundamental system of neighborhood so that they induce a topology. Then this topology must have $x+G_n$ open and so on...